# Update another table if conditions are met

Tags: mysql

as I'm working on a small app for managing metadata and I was wondering if it is possible to insert row in another table if conditions are met.

Let me follow with example: So, let's say we have table `ispu_plan`

```
CREATE TABLE `ispu_plan` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_jls` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_razina_plan` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_revizija` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `naziv_plan` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `ispu_naziv` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `id_mjerilo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `datum_donosenja_plana` date DEFAULT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and as I'm updating table `ispu_plan` I want to update another table (e.g. `ispu_plan_updated`) if certain conditions are met in `ispu_plan` with same rows from table `ispu_plan`

Using this query:

```
SELECT * FROM ispu_plan WHERE  datum_donosenja_plana BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND CURDATE()
```

I want to insert row in table `ispu_plan_updated`. Is something like this possible and can I insert rows in `ispu_plan_updated` using views?

Thank you

Comment: checkout `insert into select from...`

Comment: So to recap @svinjica, some scripts updates a row in `ispu_plan` and at the same time to update a row from `ispu_plan_updated` if some conditions are met ?

Comment: @DanIonescu Yes, true!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a trigger to achieve that:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS ispu_plan_trigger;

DELIMITER |

CREATE TRIGGER ispu_plan_trigger AFTER UPDATE ON ispu_plan
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
-- example condition with update:
IF NEW.datum_donosenja_plana >= '2017-01-01' THEN
UPDATE ispu_plan_updated SET naziv_plan = 'some_value' WHERE id = NEW.id
LIMIT 1;
END IF;
END;

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thank you dan for fast response. I will test this ASAP

Comment: No problem, just replace with your own conditions and custom update

Comment: .I did tried it but nothing happened when i inserted row in ispu_plan even if conditions are met. To be fair I'm one step closer with your trigger. I don't if I explained well enough but I want to update new table with same values that meet given conditions